# Set a parents parent css using javascript/ knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've got some checkboxes within a table and I want to the css of their parent  to be dependent upon whether it's checkbox is checked or not. I can't seem to get this to work and was hoping you could point me in the right direction.

At the moment, I've got a setCss() function on the checkbox 'onclick' method but am getting the resource undefined error.

I've added [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ccvk/7/)

```
function setCss() {
if (this.checked)
    $(this).closest('td').className = "selected";
else
    $(this).closest('td').className = "deselected";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite simply using the knockout [`css`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding:

```
 <td data-bind="css: {'selected': selected,'deselected': !selected() }">
      <!-- existing content -->
 </td>
```

I've updated [**your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ccvk/9/) to work in this way.

This binding means "set the 'selected' class if `selected()` evaluates to a truthy value, and set the 'deselected' class if it evaluates to falsey".

You could also neaten up your CSS by using a `:not(selected)` instead of an explicit `deselected` class